# Implementing SharePoint Sync Framework API?

Tags: 2010, sync

Could you please help me out on how to sync several SharePoint lists in different environments?

Scenario:

I have several SharePoint lists in environment (A) and each list of them contains items. Also, I have exactly the same SharePoint lists in environment (B) and each list of them contains the same items as environment (A). Therefore, environment (A) and environment (B) are identical.

My question is: How to make sure that if items of environment (A) have changed, then, the changes will be reflected on environment (B) ?

Of course, I have heard of Microsoft Sync Framework for SharePoint and I saw: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538641.aspx) But I didn't find any code sample for that at all.

I would greatly appreciate your inputs !

Answer (score 2):

In general synchronizations like this is not a good idea? There's a whole lot of things that must be considered - not just the data in the lists. What about permissions and possibly custom code? What if the environments differ in auth schemas etc.

First of all do you need a synchronization between these lists and why? What's the purpose?

Secondly, I don't think the Sync framework (as you linked to) is the way to go here. It's mainly done for synchronizing with external client apps such as SharePoint Workspace (methinks that the only reason that these API's are documented is to satisfy EU rules :-).

I would suggest that you first of all make sure that you really need synchronization and not just master-copy relationship. Then I would take one of two approaches.

1. Use an event reciever on the lists that does the copying between the lists
2. Create a timer job or external client app that takes advantage of the [Change Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417456.aspx).

Comment: Dear Wictor,Thank you so much for your valuable input. I liked the second approach but could you please provide me any code sample about how to use the Change Log.

Answer (score 0):

I havent worked with the SharePoint implementation of Sync, but I found some samples that might be useful for you.

Check them out here:

http://www.chakkaradeep.com/post/SharePoint-2010-ListsGetListItemChangesWithKnowledge-Method.aspx

Comment: Thanks Anders, I actually have read this article before but it wasn't that useful for me. I mean I couldn't learn from it how to impelement and also the author talked about only one method and not the another.

Comment: ill ping the author and see if he can elaborate here